# Chromecast custom receiver: Current displayed frame of video element is not updated to the frame of new position when video element is on pause

Tags: video-streaming, html5-video, chromecast, http-live-streaming

I'm writing to ask you for help. I develop a custom receiver which plays hls stream. And I find that if you scrub video when it's on pause, current displayed frame of video element is not updated to the frame of new position.

For example, I pause video and then I scrub video to new position which is few minutes forward. As a result, I see in logs that 'SEEK' event of 
cast.receiver.MediaManager is fired, 'seeking' and 'seeked' events of  video element are fired too. I also see that 'canPlay' event is fired. But frame of video element isn't changed, frame of previous position is still shown. 
Only when I resume playing (for example, by executing 'videoElement.play()' command) current frame is updated and video plays correctly from new position.

Did anybody have the same problem? I would very much appreciate it if you could help me to find solution for it?

With best regards,
John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that I found main reason of the issue. I checked it on all of my chromecast devices (two 1'gen devices and two 2'gen devices, firmware version - 1.20.66189) and found that it was reproduced on 3 devices and it wasn't on one 1'gen device. I also checked behavior of official YouTube receiver app. And yes, YouTube receiver has the same issue on 3 devices and it hasn't on one 1'gen device. As a result, I think that this is device specific issue.

Comment: I also registered issue at google-cast-sdk issue tracker